# Intersection points of two exponential decay functions

Tags: analysis, functions, exponential-function

I have not found much online regarding this question. It's by no means my area of research, but is a questioning I came across when writing a program.
If I have two exponential decay functions defined on the same interval $[0,1]$, how many intersection points can they have on this interval?

The two functions can be defined in the form (with $a,b,c,a',b',c' > 0$):
\begin{align}
f(x) = a + b\exp(-c x), && g(x) = a' + b'\exp(-c' x).
\end{align}
Assuming $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not equal, I seem to either find $0$, $1$ or $2$ intersection points. Would you have suggestions on how to approach this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Hint: How many points are needed to uniquely specify the three parameters $a, b, c$?

Comment: This follows directly from the theory of total positivity. If a signed measure has $k$ sign changes, its Laplace transform has at most $k$ positive roots.